# how to get Cheese to see webcam? (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: cheese

I tried Cheese but t says "There was an error playing video from the webcam" (on the Take a Photo page).  My webcam works on Skype, but nothing here.   I also tried "shotwell" but only the background is in focus, not my face.
I'd like to take a photo with my webcam.

Comment: Have you seen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245040/webcam-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-after-recent-kernel-update

Comment: Also check out https://askubuntu.com/q/797366/124466

Comment: Try luvcview, it works with more cameras than cheese.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UBUNTU 14.04 cheese booth not detect webcam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454220/ubuntu-14-04-cheese-booth-not-detect-webcam)

Comment: Did you look at that thread?  I wonder what part of it you thought applies?   It goes all over the place.   Starts out with different kernels working differently.  I'm not going to change kernels or versions.   Goes to permissions.  I figured if it works with Skype, that must mean programs have permissions to use it.   I just can't follow down too many rabbit holes.   Maybe someone has had this same issue and knows how to fix it.   Ubuntu 22.04 and usb camera.

Comment: First, it isn't a duplicate.   Second, I solved it.   I went into the "Ubuntu  Software" and looked for 'Cheese'.  There were 2 of them.   I uninstalled the one I had installed and installed the other version and that one works.  As I said, I looked through those suggestions and they were not the same, some were from totally different versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I went into the "ubuntu software' and searched for 'cheese'.   There were 2 of them.   I noted the one I installed and uninstalled it and then installed the other version.   That one hooked up with my USB camera.  Different version.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would try is reinstalling cheese. the way that you can do this is by using the command `sudo apt-get --reinstall install cheese`. If that does not fix your problem, I would suggest using a different app like OBS. Here is a Tutorial on how to take a screenshot/picture with obs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4InPqYNyO18 (I did not make this video, I just found it). There are also many different webcam apps for Linux that you can find.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).